# What is the difference between "should be cause for concern" and "is cause for concern"?

Tags: phrases, differences

Do the two phrases really mean different things? We may compare the following:

> ‘The mysterious and majestic blue hue’ emanating from Hong Kong seas **is cause for concern**, scientists say.
>
> ‘The mysterious and majestic blue hue’ emanating from Hong Kong seas **should be cause for concern**, scientists say.

What is the difference, if there is any?

Comment: Have you looked up "should" in a dictionary?

Comment: Exactly the same as _should be dead_ versus _is dead_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is General Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use these phrases interchangeably, but with the right tone, "should be cause for concern" might imply that the writer doesn't think enough concern is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking if the first sentence is saying "it is a cause" then that means it is undeniably so.

However, the second sentence is saying "it should be a cause" meaning that it should be but it technically isn't, because no one us saying that it is a cause. They are just saying it should be.
Example:

> He is a prime suspect.
>
> He should be a prime suspect.

The first is saying that he is undeniably a prime suspect, however the second one is saying he isnt, but should be.